# PHP utility function for SOAP answer

Tags: php, function, soap

I have a SOAP response that looks like this

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetShowInformationResponse xmlns="http://www.xxxx.com/xxxxWS/">
      <GetShowInformationResult>
        <CustomFields>
          <CustomField>
            <Name>string</Name>
            <Value>string</Value>
          </CustomField>
          <CustomField>
            <Name>string</Name>
            <Value>string</Value>
          </CustomField>
        </CustomFields>
      </GetShowInformationResult>
    </GetShowInformationResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

My SOAP call gives me a list of custom fields:

```
$result->GetShowInformationResult->CustomFields->CustomField
```

It answers like this (though might be object or null):

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [Name] => YouTubeID [Value] => XPCHmIOml0f ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [Name] => Episode Title [Value] => Raw Foods ) )
```

**I need to write a utility function that extracts the field I want based on the 'name' and then gives me the 'value'**. Here's what I have so far, but can't get it to work...

```
function ExtractCustomField($fieldName, $customFields) {
 // $customFields might be an object, null, or an array.
  $parsed = array();
  if (is_array($customFields) == false && $customFields != null) {
   $parsed = array($customFields);
  } elseif (is_array($customFields)) {
   $parsed = $customFields;
  }

  // loop through the fields and find the one we are looking for
  $returnValue = null;
  foreach($field as $customFields) {
   if ($field->Name == $fieldName) {
    $returnValue = $field->Value;
    break;
   }
  }

  return $returnValue;
}

ExtractCustomField('YouTubeID','$result->GetShowInformationResult->CustomFields->CustomField');
```

Comment: You pass the string `'$result->GetShowInformationResult->CustomFields->CustomField'` to the function which looks like a mistake, you most likely meant `$result->GetShowInformationResult->CustomFields->CustomField` (without the quotes).

Comment: I still get: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Please add a `var_dump($customFields);` at the very beginning of the function and report back the value. Also for `var_dump($field);` just before the `foreach` pls.

Comment: $customFields reported:
    `array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#5 (2) { ["Name"]=> string(9) "YouTubeID" ["Value"]=> string(11) "XPCHmIOml0g" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#6 (2) { ["Name"]=> string(13) "Episode Title" ["Value"]=> string(10) "Raw Fresno" } }`

Comment: and var_dump($field); ?

Comment: $field reported null

Comment: Did you perhaps use the wrong variable there in the foreach? Please double-check the name.

Comment: oops, shouldn't it be this: `foreach($customFields as $field)`.  But var_dump still returns null, `var_dump($field);
  foreach($customFields as $field) {
   if ($field->Name == $fieldName) {
    $returnValue = $field->Value;
    break;
   }
  }`

Comment: var_dump is just dumping the variable. remove it again, it was just used for inspection.

Comment: OK. Now I get a blank page, no error message. It should give me the value: XPCHmIOml0f.

Comment: I'm dumb. Working now. Thank you! `echo ExtractCustomField('YouTubeID',$result->GetShowInformationResult->CustomFields->CustomField);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm dumb and @hakre helped me solve it.

Problem was mixing up variables in the foreach, and not having the function echo. Also discovered if it returned an object I wasn't putting it into an array correctly.

```
function ExtractCustomField($fieldName, $customFields) {
// $customFields might be an object, null, or an array.
 if($customFields == null) {
   $customFields = array();       
 } else {
   $customFields = is_array($customFields) ? $customFields : array($customFields);
 }

  // loop through the fields and find the one we are looking for
  $returnValue = null;
  foreach($customFields as $field) {
   if ($field->Name == $fieldName) {
    $returnValue = $field->Value;
    break;
   }
  }

  return $returnValue;
}

echo ExtractCustomField('YouTubeID',$result->GetShowInformationResult->CustomFields->CustomField);
```

Comment: you should note what the actual problem was. it helps to write it down once :)